# Spark GroupBy to map and keep all fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to groupby in order to map a Map.

```
case class Foo(
                          domain: String,
                          site: Long,
                          reason: String,
                          list: Long,
                          policy: Long,
                          action: Long,
                         )

val f = Seq(
Foo("domain", 1, "reason1", 33, 44, 55),
  Foo("domain", 1, "reason2", 33, 44, 55),
  Foo("domain", 2, "reason3", 33, 66, 55),
  Foo("domain", 2, "reason4", 33, 66, 55),
  Foo("domain", 1, "reason5", 33, 88, 55),
)


val ds = f.toDS()
```

I know I can get the fields explicitly by:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{map, collect_list}

ds.groupBy($"site").agg(collect_list(map($"site", $"reason"))).collect()
```

But I want all fields (besides the aggregated one - `site`, basically `site` maps to all other fields in the current row) - my original case class is much larger than this, and might change. Any other way to do so without getting all col.

Any cleaner way to do so?

Using Spark 3, Scala 2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the set of fields should be known dynamically, I guess one way to go would be to read it from the dataset schema after Spark has inferred it:

```scala
val allFields = ds.schema.fields.map(st => col(st.name))
```

And since `site` should map to all fields, one simple way to contain them would be to bundle them into a `struct` at the place where you put the `$"reason"`, like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

ds.groupBy($"site").agg(collect_list(map($"site", struct(allFields:_*)))).show(truncate=false)
```

which yields:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|site|collect_list(map(site, struct(domain, site, reason, list, policy, action)))                                                |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   |[{1 -> {domain, 1, reason1, 33, 44, 55}}, {1 -> {domain, 1, reason2, 33, 44, 55}}, {1 -> {domain, 1, reason5, 33, 88, 55}}]|
|2   |[{2 -> {domain, 2, reason3, 33, 66, 55}}, {2 -> {domain, 2, reason4, 33, 66, 55}}]                                         |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Although maybe the `site` in the map is redundant since it's also in the group-by key? This is a simpler version that just builds an array of `struct`:

```scala
ds.groupBy($"site").agg(collect_list(struct(allFields:_*)).as("foos")).show(truncate=false)
```

Which yields:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|site|foos                                                                                                  |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   |[{domain, 1, reason1, 33, 44, 55}, {domain, 1, reason2, 33, 44, 55}, {domain, 1, reason5, 33, 88, 55}]|
|2   |[{domain, 2, reason3, 33, 66, 55}, {domain, 2, reason4, 33, 66, 55}]                                  |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```